# honda civic hybrid 2006

Tags: honda, transmission, hybrid

I drive a Honda Civic 2006 hybrid. The transmission is faulty. I notice a loud noise while accelerating and it wouldn't change gears while accelerating. But I've been using it like this for the past six months and running. I was told it can't be fixed that I need to replace it entirely. Another mechanic said it can be fixed. Please advise me if you have any experience.

Comment: Any servicing - have you checked fluid levels?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a CVT?